# Bijection from $[0,1]$ to $(1, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I've come across many different versions of this question on here, but not any that map the $[0,1]$ to $(1, \infty)$.

I was thinking that it must be piece-wise defined, since the endpoints 0 and 1 will be the trickiest part of defining the bijection... The only method of doing this that I could come up with would be to possibly show a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $(1,2)$, then construct another bijection from $(1,2)$ to $(1, \infty)$, and then the composition will be from $[0,1]$ to $(1, \infty)$, but I haven't been able to come up with any function that can do this... Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** There is a simple (continuous) bijection from $(0,1)\to (1, \infty)$. So if you can find a bijection from $[0,1] \to (0,1)$ then you're done. One way to do this is in two steps: find a bijection $[0,1]\to(0,1]$ and then find another from $(0,1]\to(0,1)$.

To find a bijection from $[0,1]\to(0,1]$, you intuitively want to fix "most of" $[0,1]$, but you need to send $0$ to somewhere that isn't $0$. And wherever you send $0$ can't be sent to itself, so has to be sent somewhere else. And wherever you send that to also has to be sent somewhere else... and so on.

Let's try sending $0$ to $\frac12$. And we can send $\frac12$ to $\frac14$, and $\frac14$ to $\frac 18$, and so on, and fix everything that isn't of the form $\frac1{2^n}$ for an integer $n \ge 2$. Can you show that this gives a bijection?

Can you do something similar to find a bijection from $(0,1]\to(0,1)$?

Comment: so map 0 to 1/2, 1 to 1 and then any number not of the form 1/(2^n) to itself..??

Comment: Yes, and $\frac{1}{2^n}$ to $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ for all $n \gt 1$. The idea is that if $f:[0,1]\to(0,1]$ is our bijection, then $f(0) \ne 0$, so $f(f(0)) \ne f(0)$ and so on. So $x_k=f^k(0)$ must be some infinite sequence in $(0,1]$ with no repeated terms, such that $f(x_k) = x_{k+1}$. But apart from that sequence, everything else can just map to itself.

Comment: What I have so far is 
f(x) = 1/2 if x=0
f(x) = 1/(2^n+1) if x = 1/(2^n) 
f(x) = 1 if x = 1
f(x) = x if x is not of the form 1/(2^n)

is that it for f: [0,1] -> (0,1]? Then I need a bijection from (0,1] to (1,inf) where the 1 IS NOT included...

Comment: I understand the part that you explained, that is similar to showing [0,1] to (0,1), but I don't know how to relate it to the (1,inf) part of the mapping

Comment: I misread the interval as $[1,\infty)$. But can you generalise the idea that I just gave you to find a bijection $(0,1] \to (0,1)$. The same ideal will work, but this time its $1$ that has to be mapped elsewhere. So you will have a string of bijections $[0,1]\to(0,1]\to(0,1)$. Can you find a bijection $(0,1)\to(1,\infty)$?

Comment: I've edited the answer slightly - does that help at all?

Comment: If I have a bijection from [0,1] to (0,1), how do I show that it extends to [0,1] -> (1,inf)??

Comment: Can you think of a bijection from $(0,1)\to(1,\infty)$? There is a simple continuous one.

Comment: Would something like (1/x) work? Or would it have to be (1/x) - 1...?

Comment: one of those two is exactly what you're after. Can you work out which one it has to be? If $0<x\lt1$ what values does $\frac1x$ take?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a piece-wise function defined where 0 maps to some value y1 not equal to 1 (say 2). Then you can manipulate the period and height of tan(x) such that  tan(0) = 1 and tan(1) is infinite.