# Find a bijection from $(a,b]$ to $(c, \infty)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Find a bijection from $(a,b]$ to $(c, \infty)$.

I tried to solve this but it's hard. I guess there are steps and the problem can be broken down to smaller problems. Help anyone?

HOW ABOUT THIS SOLUTION?

(0,1) --> (1,infinity) by f(x) = 1/x 
so (0,1) --> (c, infinity) by f(x) = 1/x + c
 and we left to prove: (0,1) is bijection to (a,b], WHICH IS SIMPLY A LINE EQUATION MX + B?

Comment: Question first before I try to answer.  Do you know how to find a bijection from $(a,b)$ to $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: maybe from (a,b) to (0,1) first? (line: mx+b) i dunno. maybe (a,b) to (0,1) is a line equation and then (0,1) to (0, infinity) by function f(x) = 1/x

Comment: Consider for example the tangent function, it bijects $(0,\pi/2)$ to $(0,\infty)$.  You can modify that to map any open finite interval $(a,b)$ to $(0,\infty)$ by scaling.

Comment: But that doesn't completely solve the problem you still have $b$.  That's where you need to get tricky.

Comment: I don't understand.. so what is the full solution? you break up the problem to strages? can you use (0,1) ?/

Comment: Compare [Bijection from $[0,1]$ to $(1, \infty)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131092/bijection-from-0-1-to-1-infty) – That is about mapping a closed interval, not a half-closed, but you'll find the main idea there.

Comment: What about this solution: (0,1) --> (1,infinity) by f(x) = 1/x    so (0,1) --> (c, infinity) by f(x) = 1/x + c, and we left to prove: (0,1) is bijection to (a,b], so how do I continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

We have bijection $f: (a;b) \to (c;\infty)$ given by the equation

$$
f(x)=\frac{(b-a)c}{x-a} .
$$

And there is a bijection  $g:(a;b] \to (a;b)$ namely

$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x+a}{2}, & \text{when } x=\frac{(2^n-1) \cdot a +b}{2^{n}} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N}; \\
x, & \text{in other cases.}
\end{cases}
$$

Composition $f \circ g$ gives us desired bijection.

Comment: wow.. this seems hard... how did you came up with equations (b-a)c/(x-a)??

Comment: No, it is $f \circ g$, but the function $g$ is wrong I will fix it in a second.

Comment: Basically you want a function which tends to $\infty$ on one of ends of an interval $(a;b)$, and also with a property that $\lim_{x \to \text{other end of a given interval}} f(x) = c$.

Comment: but still.. how did you came up with the equations??? can you explain? what is (b-a)c/(x-a)?

Comment: What exactly you are asking of?

Comment: (b-a)c/(x-a) equation..